# Size of array of pointers to char

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

I printed the size of this global variable and the output was 20.  I'm trying to understand how it's not just 15 since there's 5 elements, each one is size of 3 (including the \0 at the end of each one).

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* arrChar[5] = { "hh","jj","kk","zz","xx" };

int main()
{
printf("size = %d\n", sizeof(arrChar));
}
```

I don't know if there's a connection but if we combined all the numbers here it would be 20, still I don't understand how the number of elements (5) added to the size of the elements in the array (15) is making any sense.

[image]

Comment: Hint: What is the size of five *pointers* on your platform? .That is, after all, what is actually in that array.

Comment: `since there's 5 elements, each one is size of 3` No. You have an array of pointers. Each pointer has a size of 4.

Comment: You would be correct for the type of `char arrChar[5][3]`, but `char* arrChar[5]` has an entirely different type.

Comment: the size of `*char`is normally 4 Byte on a 32 Bit machine. So the size of the array is 5*4 Byte = 20 Byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that 15 bytes are occupied somewhere in memory. But that information is generally of no use.

For `char str[] = "1";` , `sizeof(str)` is same as `sizeof(char*)`, it's always the size of a pointer (4 bytes in your 32-bit settings)

For `char str[] = "1234567";` `sizeof(str)` is still the same (use `strlen` for string's length)

If you have 5 `str`s then its size is 4 x 5.

You can use `sizeof(arrChar)/sizeof(*arrChar)` to get the total number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the actual data are string literal stored in some read-only section of memory. The data isn't allocated inside `arrChar`, just the addresses to the data.

No matter what you set each pointer to point at, `sizeof(arrChar)` will always yield `sizeof(char*) * 5`. In case pointers are 4 bytes large, then 4*5=20.